# Find out available options in /etc/default/grub

Tags: linux, grub

I see that in various Linux distributions different options/variables are used in `/etc/default/grub`. This might be because of different versions of grub2 used (I might be wrong?) On the net I can find distro specific documentation, like for [gentoo](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GRUB2). I was wondering if there is something like a manpage, included with the system, documenting which options are recognized in  `/etc/default/grub` and what they do.

Edit: I found the [online docu](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Simple-configuration.html#Simple-configuration) myself. Still I am wondering if I can find that info on the system without visiting the net.

Answer (score 0):

The Arch Wiki is an excellent resource for all things Linux.  It is of course tailored for the Arch distribution but nonetheless a good portion of the information carries over to all distributions.

[Arch Wiki GRUB](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Grub)